# How to remove columns from the list of instances in Amazon AWS EC2

Tags: amazon-ec2

I have started to use Amazon EC2 service and the problem I am trying to solve is as follows: in the list of instances I have a lot of columns (most of them are the same) and I would like to hide/remove some of them, but the problem is that I don’t know the meaning of the most of them.

If my question was not clear enough, here is a screenshot:

[image]

P.S.: Also, if someone will be able to explain me the meaning of the columns, it will be really nice, but this is not the point of the question: - instance - AMI ID - Root Device - Virtualization

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can select which columns to display by clicking on the cogwheel in the top right corner of the Instance view in your EC2 management console.

[image]

It will display a list of checkboxes for each instance attribute that you can choose to display or not as a column in the Instance view:

[image]